# How to give Text field range to best_in_place in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, best-in-place

Hi I am using simple form text field in my model. After creation I will add best in place to edit and update. now i want to give max and min length of that particular field please help me how to proceed it.

I need word wrap for best in place

Thanks for advance.

**batchnotification.rb**

```
    class BatchNotification
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps


  field :finalCount, type: Float
  field :message, type: String
  field :approved, type: Boolean
  field :batch_id, type: Integer
  field :user_id, type:Integer


  validates_presence_of :approved
  validates_presence_of :message
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 5


  belongs_to :batch
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :calculated_batch_counts

end
```

**index.html.erb**

```
   <%= best_in_place notification, :message %>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try

**html_attrs:** Hash of html arguments such as maxlength.

```
<%= best_in_place  :message, :html_attrs => {:maxlength => 50} %>
```

Comment: But i need word wrap for best in place

Answer (score 0):

validates :message, length: { minimum: 2 }